# Ensure order when select two rows using two identifiers on the same column

Tags: query, order-by

I'm trying to write a query to retrieve exactly two rows from a table using the same column for identification.

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE name = $1 OR name = $2;
```

Is there any way to ensure that the result for `name = $1` is the first result returned and `name = $2` is the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
WHERE name IN ($1, $2)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = $1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to arrange the arguments and their respective sorting values as a (derived) table, join that table and use the sorting column in ORDER BY:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  teams AS t
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT $1 AS name, 1 AS sort
      UNION ALL
      SELECT $2 AS name, 2 AS sort
    ) AS s ON t.name = s.name
ORDER BY
  s.sort ASC
;
```